# How to get the in Delphi the chunk IDAT from a png image?

Tags: delphi, png, chunks

I am trying to get the data from the chunk IDATA data from this png picture. When this picture is opened in a TextEditor I can appreciate the chunk IDAT after PLTE and before IEND, the length is about 336, of course is not 0, but when I get the datasize width Delphi the result is 0 and data is empty.

[image]

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 png: TPngImage;
 i,size: Integer;
 Buffer: Pointer;
begin
      for i := 0 to pred(png.Chunks.Count) do
      begin
       if(png.Chunks.Item[i].Name='IDAT')then
       begin
          Buffer := png.Chunks.Item[i].Data;//this is empty
          size:= png.Chunks.Item[i].DataSize;// is 0, How is that possible ?
          break;
       end;
      end;
end;
```

@TLama, @Remy I try this but not working:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 png: TPngImage;
 i,size: Integer;
 Buffer: Pointer;
 stream: TStream;
begin
 png := TPngImage.Create;
 png.LoadFromFile('C:\temp\example.png');

 stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  for i := 0 to pred(png.Chunks.Count) do
  begin
    if(png.Chunks.Item[i] is TChunkIDAT )then
    begin
      TChunkIDAT(Png.Chunks.Item[I]).SaveToStream(stream);
      if Assigned(Stream) then
      begin
        Buffer := AllocMem(Stream.Size);
        Stream.Position := 0;
        Stream.Read(Buffer^, Stream.Size);
      end;
    end;
```

end;

The result of Buffer is:

IDATxÚíÙÙƒ Ðæÿ?Ú.V¥H åN|r_„„ ‹þÞTË»Vn†Á„s[dHÁ¬T¶1c•…®=Õ¨Íèì#½Z˜q+–'Š£–,‡Æ¬Ù2sñ`KPÖ÷bïÔoÏÓÍ¬´ãËfZÒôwSîjE¸‰w6bÜ<îQî)R´{î~MŠww” îGEÂñî›Â÷%/xÁ~0ÆòS/xx¾ßâ„[Ü.·¯Æ$pg'Üiw>Æep9wšÍú8Ëµ<—#ÝÈìyÑ‚\¦-ÌÞZÓùjKº3CodÔ$ôöxF«ëN#¸Y¥MÎ;Ô¹×ª¦Z^0ø  Cý?Dã2k‚

But if you open the image, the IDAt is this one:

X…íØÙ
Ã0Ðì¿tEŽ6vt‘jsgèÇ¢–eÆœ×"Õ‹€„ð´ y<£Æí¼²«X']É:èjÖH#XbŸh¤Û‘±l›Æ»÷2Ã½“9î¯Ìr¿ež{•™îYæº‡ÌvwYóÝ¬‚î[žð„Q°ÆrÔ ï[põÑm™º½Z×$tÝI×uýXwÐÝ@àt“Ë=H?°(ÚÀ"h#[M;ØJÚÉÙ5oÇÕžF#xjçdë$ê/²‚¯©Œ

Comment: That's because the `TChunkIDAT` instance does not use any of the ancestor's `TChunk` methods which would call `ResizeData`. Why is it so for this particular image I don't know. Why do you need to know that anyway ?

Comment: And how to get an IDAT chunk ? Do not test for `Name` but rather use e.g. `if Png.Chunks.Item[I] is TChunkIDAT then TChunkIDAT(Png.Chunks.Item[I]).SaveToStream(YourStream);`

Comment: @TLama: There is nothing wrong with checking `item.Name='IDAT'` instead of `item is TChunkIDAT`. Either way works fine, but checking the `Name` is not subject to the overhead of RTTI lookups.

Comment: @Remy, I know that both works but I would still prefer checking the class type rather than a value which (even though won't ever change) has nothing to do with the class type itself. And I will do that personally for every object I'll ever hard-cast as long as it's not a *home-made* code (where we use enumerations to identify the class type, not just because of the overhead you've mentioned but mostly because you can easily switch with a `case` instead of multiple `if` statements between class types).

Comment: Be aware that a PNG can contain (often contains) several IDAT chunks.

Answer (score 2):

The `IDAT` chunk contains the actual image data, but the `TChunkIDAT` item for that chunk does not keep a copy of the image data inside of itself, which is why its `DataSize` is 0.  When loading the `IDAT` chunk, `TChunkIDAT` decodes the image data and stores it in the `ImageData` and `ImageAlpha` members of the `TChunkIHDR` item for the `IHDR` chunk.

Answer (score 0):

After the whole investigation day, I was able to create my own function to get IDAT chunk, I post for everyone needs it.

```
function GetChunk(fileName,chunkName:String;var chunkLen:Integer):Pointer;
var
 bytes,iData: TArray<byte>;
 data,chunkType: AnsiString;
 i,p,cont:Integer;
 function getBytes(data:AnsiString;pos,num:Integer):Integer;
  var
   i:Integer;
  begin
    Result := 0;
    for i := 1 to num do
    begin
     Result := Result * 256;
     Result := Result + ORD(data[pos+i]);
  end;
end;
begin
   if(not FileExists(FileName))then
     Exit(nil);

    data := '';
    bytes := System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    for i := Low(bytes) to High(bytes) do
     data := data + chr(bytes[i]);

    p := 8;
    while (p<Length(bytes)) do
    begin
       chunkLen := getBytes(data,p,4);
       chunkType := copy(data,p+5,4);
       if(chunkType=chunkName)then
       begin
         inc(p,8);
         break;
       end;

     inc(p,chunkLen+12);
   end;
   SetLength(iData,chunkLen+1);
   cont := 0;
   for i := p to p+chunkLen do
   begin
     iData[cont] := bytes[i];
     inc(cont);
   end;
  Result := iData;
end;
```